# how to get latitude and longitude boundary points of a suburb in google maps

Tags: maps

When we type into google maps a suburb, it gives the subrubs region's boundary and the area in a particular colour. I would like to do this exact thing. But I need a way of getting the suburbs boundary latitude and longitude coordinates to draw my polygons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Google does not expose the information about the suburb's boundary.  You could store the points in boundary yourself, and display them with a Polygon.

For the US, the Census Bureau has information about metropolitan boundaries, see http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/

For Canada, look here: http://geodepot.statcan.gc.ca/2006/180506051805140305/06180505162102/92-160-072305/2006001/200102120519/20010212055_4_1-eng.htm

Good luck!