# Google Maps API - Mark a street from start to end of a suburb

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xamarin, shapefile

I'm not sure if this belongs in StackOverflow as it's not technically coding, but I can't think of where this would belong.

Currently, we're working on a mobile application that we're thinking of using the Google Maps API to return the start and end of a street's intersections in a particular suburb.

For example, if Suburb A encompasses half of Street B, it will only highlight that section of Street B.

After reading the following articles ([Getting long/lat points of a suburb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216598/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-boundary-points-of-a-suburb-in-google-maps), [getting start/end co-ords of a street](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646304/google-maps-api-v3-get-start-and-end-coordinates-of-a-street)), they basically summarise that

> I believe that Google does not expose the information about the suburb's boundary. You could store the points in boundary yourself, and display them with a Polygon.

and

> The Google Maps API v3 doesn't do that. You need to find a different data source or manually determine the coordinates.

so obviously that eliminates Google Maps. Is there any other map API that can be used both on mobile and web browsers that can display these highlighted street points?

Another option we are considering is that we manually insert the co-ordinates into a database and have the application/s read from that, and do as the first linked answer sort of implies, manually draw the routes?

Please don't hesitate to let me know if this question needs modification or to be moved to another exchange.

Comment: *I'm not sure if this belongs in StackOverflow* definitely not ... *Is there any other map API* => **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** ... *or should we* => *Don't ask about: Requests for lists of things, **polls, opinions,** discussions, etc.*

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for pointing out that which I already knew. Can I ask you provide something useful, as to which exchange this would suit, instead of simply voting to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, and I think found the answer (note this is for Australia, but a similar process could work elsewhere).
http://www.datalicious.com/blog/2012/03/19/free-australian-suburb-boundary-data-for-mapp/
This might help. They:

> We used the Australian Bureau of Statistics data, which offers the suburb boundaries as an ESRI shapefile. This data in essence offers the perimeters of every suburb in Australia using GPS coordinates. The ABS offers some its boundary data in more friendly formats, but many are not – hence the blog post. The process involved importing the ESRI shapefile into an open-source program called Quantum GIS that allowed an export of the suburb boundaries into a format we could work with (i.e. CSV format).

If you could pull coordinates out of this you could then use this in google maps to find the suburb boundaries concerning the streets you want, and only select the section of the street within the suburb you want.

I'm sure there are other solutions, but I don't think it is possible directly through the Google Maps API (as indicated here: [Accessing google maps area coordinates (suburb boundaries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485954/accessing-google-maps-suburb-boundaries)).

Comment: I'll give this a go for sure, it seems like the way forward. The question you've linked to has some good material as well to solve this issue, and I think I'll go with a hybrid approach of the shapefiles mixed with a database integration. Thanks for your input, I'll mark this as the answer. Cheers!